# How to create file on iphone using phonegap2.0

Tags: javascript, ios, html

I am new to iphone and phonegap also. Now i want to create `file` in iphone using phonegap. I followed the below link:

```
 "http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File"
```

In this link there is one html file with javascript. So i followed the coding. When i run that coding i got the output only in html  tag content.

```
I have attach that coding with my output.
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>FileReader Example</title>![enter image description here][1]

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
    }

    function gotFile(file){
        readDataUrl(file);
        readAsText(file);
    }

    function readDataUrl(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            console.log("Read as data URL");
            console.log(evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function readAsText(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            console.log("Read as text");
            console.log(evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        console.log(error.code);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Read File</p>
  </body>
</html>



"TestPhonegapApp[9589:707] CDVPlugin class CDVDevice (pluginName: Device) does not exist.
2012-09-11 12:02:13.719 TestPhonegapApp[9589:707] ERROR: Plugin 'Device' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist.
2012-09-11 12:02:13.722 TestPhonegapApp[9589:707] FAILED pluginJSON = {"className":"Device","methodName":"getDeviceInfo","arguments":["Device1"]}"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi! I think the example you used is for reading a file. You may wanna check how to write a file: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter . Hope this link helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried the coding under your instruction. But sorry i got the same output. Please give me some more idea to clear the issue. I am using phonegap2.0 version.

Comment: ... sorry for the delay... crazy crash here.. Anyway, did you modify your file `Cordova.plist`? Did your console showed anything?

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have edited the cordova.plist in my question for your reference. And also i have received some error messages in xcode4.3 debugger console. When i run the code in device i got these messages. I have edited that error messages in my question for your reference.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16529/discussion-between-littm-and-gopinath-m)